# Adding columns to a matrix in loop

Tags: python, loops, numpy, for-loop, matrix

I am trying to add selective columns from one matrix to another matrix in loop when condition becomes true. I have tried various combinations but it adds in rows with np.append etc commands, Any help is appreciated. Thanks

I have tried np.append, np.concatenation, np.hstack commands but not getting the desired soltuion.

```
n,m=np.shape(K)
Z=np.array([])
for number in range(m):
    A=function
    if A<0.05:
        Z = np.append(Z,np.vstack(K[:,number]))
```

I want Z matrix with columns of K that satisfy the condition A. Like 
Z=[K[:,3] K[:,8] K[:,10]]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. That's a good start, but what would be best for us to solve your problem is a [mcve]. We should be able to copy and paste your code in our favorite IDE and correct it accordingly to get the **output** you should also provide. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [21]: Z=np.array([])
In [22]: Z.shape
Out[22]: (0,)
```

How do you expect to add something to an array with this shape?

`np.append` does work, but only because if first makes sure `Z` is atleast 1d, that is it ravels it.

```
In [23]: np.append(Z,np.arange(10))
Out[23]: array([0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.])
```

We need some sort of big bold letters in `numpy`, saying DO NOT TRY TO APPEND (or concatenate or stack) ARRAYS IN A LOOP.

Did you try building a list of columns, and then using just one concatenate?

```
alist = []
for i in [3,8,10]:
    alist.append(K[:,[i]])
print(alist)
Z = np.concatenate(alist, axis=1)
# Z=[K[:,3] K[:,8] K[:,10]]
```

Or

```
alist = []
alist.append(3); alist.append(8); alist.append(10)
Z = K[:,alist]
```

Repeatedly concatenating arrays has two big problems - it is slow, and it is hard to get started.  That (0,) shape array is hot a valid substitute for the empty list.

If you need to do things iteratively, think lists.  list append is relatively fast, and simple to use.

Comment: I am new to python and didn't know much about it, however Thanks for your kind response.

Comment: But evidently you know enough Python to use the list append, and to attempt to imitate it in `numpy`.  `np.append` really needs some big bold warning notes.  Too many people misuse it.  At least you realized that it didn't operate in-place.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy is actually meant for fast/robust matrix operations, such as multiplication, addition etc.

Since, you are dealing with sort rows/columns tables structure and manipulations. I strongly recommend you to use [Pandas Dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html)

You can easily add columns or even merge two matrices based on condition (yes, like sql joins).

Look at [df.assign](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#assigning-new-columns-in-method-chains)

```
df = pd.Dataframe(npArray)
df.assign('newcolumn', yourNewColumnValuesAsList)
```